# Como atualizar dados no Google Maps

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tenho um app em Ionic que faz uso do google maps e exibi informações cadastradas pelo usuário, através de um formulário.
Toda vez que o usuário informar novos dados, esses novos dados devem aparecer no mapa.
A minha dúvida é a seguinte, como monitorar, alterar as informações exibidas no content do infowindow?

HTML do formulário:

```
<ion-view title="Denúncia" hide-back-button="false">
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" class="has-header">
<form class="list">
    <div ng-controller="denResCtrl">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <div class="input-label">
                  Nº do endereço
            </div>
          <input type="text" ng-model="denuncia.numeroEndereco">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <div class="input-label">
                  Data
            </div>
          <input type="date" ng-model="denuncia.dataDenun">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <div class="input-label">
                  Hora
            </div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="23:00" ng-model="denuncia.horaDenun">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input item-select">
        Tipo
            <select name="tipo" ng-model="denuncia.tipoDenun">
              <option value="" selected>Selecionar</option>
              <option value="Furto" selected>Furto</option>
              <option value="Roubo">Roubo</option>
              <option value="Sequestro">Sequestro</option>
              <option value="Arrombamento veicular">Arrombamento veicular</option>
              <option value="Tentativa de assalto">Tentativa de assalto</option>
              <option value="Arrombamento">Arrombamento</option>
              <option value="Roubo de veiculo">Roubo de veículo</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <div class="input-label">
              Breve descrição
        </div>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <textarea ng-model="denuncia.descricao" rows="5" cols="5"></textarea>
        </label>
        <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="fazerDenuncia(denuncia)">Denunciar</button>
    </div>
</form>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Controller que exibe o mapa e as informações do formulário

```
.controller('MapaResCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {

$rootScope.diaDenun;
$rootScope.hora;
$rootScope.tipo;
$rootScope.des;
$rootScope.coordenadas;


var mapOptions = {
    //center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
    $rootScope.myLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude),
        map: map,
        title: "My Location",
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "Dia da denúncia "+$rootScope.diaDenun+" Hora: "+$rootScope.hora+" Tipo: "+$rootScope.tipo+" Descrição: "+$rootScope.des
      });

    infowindow.open(map,$rootScope.myLocation);
});

$scope.map = map;

})
```

Como os dados são exibidos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se vc usar o ngMap, vai ser muito vai fácil! https://ngmap.github.io/

Comment: @user1576978, bem legal, cheio de opções, mas para o que eu quero não encontrei.
O mais próximo foi o que eu escrevo num campo e aparece no infowindow, mas o que escreverei é preenchido em um formulário, antes do mapa aparecer.